# "Related Accounts" not showing all my accounts?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts

On my "related accounts" tab, I have 4 or 5 accounts showed. But I actually have more than that! I can login to other SE sites which show the same 4 or 5 accounts but not the others.

I have the same openid (google) on all the sites.

Comment: Here's an [example profile](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/12038/michelemarcon?tab=accounts) that looks associated with the others sites, [but isn't listed in other sites' associated accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155636/michelemarcon?tab=accounts).

Comment: I don't know if it is related, however on my SE history I have performed these steps: 1 created an account with OpenID; 2 added an alternate openid (google) which in turn had a third party email address associated with it; 3 created a gmail account, which in turn switched my google account from my old email to the new gmail account.

Comment: According to various posts, you need at least one OpenID that is shared across every single account for association to work properly. It doesn't necessarily need to be the primary OpenID, I don't think. If you don't have one that is shared across every one, then that'd be the source of the problem. But if you do, then something else seems to be unusual.

Comment: For a period of time all the accounts were showed correctly, but at a certain point (It was probably when I created a gmail account) many account turned invisible.

Comment: I have the same issue - my serverfault profile's account tab shows my SO account, but I cannot see my SF account from my SO account page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to your user page
2. click on the accounts tab
3. click "Clear all Stack Exchange associations"
4. wait for the page to re-load
5. click "associate"

In my experience this fixes it 99% of the time.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that. The `Clear all...` button did what it said, the profile then said something like "other accounts found". Clicking `Associate...` just associated the "Area51" account. Repeating this procedure fixed it, the SO profile now lists 12 sites (including itself and the previously missing ones). Confusing ...

Comment: @tak it takes a few minutes to sync across the network. You have to be patient.

Comment: So maybe your answer should additionally say "6. Keep waiting"? ;-)

Comment: Hm - I just tried that, but then I can't click anything anymore

Comment: it just shows this message: "This account's associations are changing, the data below is in flux."

Comment: @inq how does it look now? That text should probably be updated to say "check again in an hour."

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently seeing the same issue; I've got multiple accounts on the SE network, and not all of them are listed. But it seems there's just one account missing, so maybe this'll help to track down the problem.

My scenario is as follows:

- primary openid is the Stackexchange openid
- secondary openid is my own url (which works as an alias for a verisign openid)
- all accounts have both openids registered in the same order

The one I'm currently not seeing from any of the accounts is https://german.stackexchange.com/ - could that be because the beta phase is not yet 100%?

It's not related to beta in general, because in that case I wouldn't see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ listed. That one is still in beta too, but Area51 lists it as 100%.

However, if that were the reason, why would it be listed in the "all sites" dropdown?

Comment: did you try clicking the "clear all associations" button on the accounts tab of your user profile, then re-associating?

Comment: no repro -- looks fine to me now http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1583/takrl?tab=accounts and http://german.stackexchange.com/users/555/takrl?tab=accounts

Comment: It does now, after doing what you said (twice). Thanks!