# Why does "home improvement" not appear among my Stack Exchange sites on my profile?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Related Accounts” not showing all my accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76687/related-accounts-not-showing-all-my-accounts)

https://stackexchange.com/users/e07fd23a-2666-4e06-a44e-8ad56bbb4fcf?tab=accounts

I can't find Home Improvement there even though I have an account there and even though it is linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this applies...

I use my (horribly ignored) website as my OpenId delegate, and this has happened to me on a couple sites.

The problem is when you do this:

[image: Clicking the OpenId button]

<sup><sup><sup>Stop snickering, perv</sup></sup></sup>

when ***you should have clicked on "More OpenID options..." and done this:***

[image]

<sup><sup><sup>omg how old are you? stop it!</sup></sup></sup>

I have an account on myOpenId, so it merrily logs me into the website.  But my primary account is associated with my OpenId delegate.  The system allows me to gently fall into a pit of fail, from which it took me awhile to figure out WTH was wrong.

Comment: `+1` just for the images lol

Answer (score 2):

Dissociate all of your accounts. Then re-associate.  Then wait an hour.  It should be fixed.

Comment: Ps. I think this may be related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89986/associating-with-other-ses-how-to-add-an-orphaned-account-to-my-profile)

Comment: And maybe [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76687/160382)