# Account association with english.stackexchange fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

I have an [english SE account](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10797/igor-milla), and for some reason it doesn't want to associate itself with my other SE accounts.

It's 14 days old, so it's not a timing issue. I use the same open id for all accounts.

I tried to push <kbd>Copy English Language and Usage profile to all Stack Exchange accounts</kbd> couple of times in a last two weeks, bit with no results. And strangest thing here, I cannot event see this account on a profile page of english SE, I can see all my other profiles there but not this one.

I cannot see it on my StackExchange network profile page, BUT I can see notification from it on my StackExchange inbox.

Am i missing something obvious, or it's a real bug here?

Comment: Should you see this again at some point, look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76687/160382) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleared and reinstated your account associations on English.SE, and it seems to be working now, as far as I can tell.